# Add simple line "Pubkey::new_unique()" breaks my Solana Program

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana

does anyone know why introducing a simple line like "Pubkey::new_unique()" inside https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/master/src/program-rust/src/lib.rs#L22 will make the program fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of that function uses global data.  Programs cannot use global data